# Autocomplete function fires before minLength value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm writing autocomplete function that should be fired with third element written:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        serviceUrl: '{{contextPath}}/someUrl',
        paramName: "suggestion",
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert("test");
        },
        transformResult: function(response) {
            return {
                suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {
                    return { value: item.x, data: item.y };
                })
            };
        },
    });
});
```

But, this function fires with the first one.
Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Ajax AutoComplete? (https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)

If so, the right option is called "minChars" not "minLength".

So try using:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').autocomplete({
            minChars: 3,
            serviceUrl: '{{contextPath}}/someUrl',
            paramName: "suggestion",
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    alert("test");
            },
            transformResult: function(response) {
                return {
                  suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {
                  return { value: item.x, data: item.y};
               })
             };
           },
        });
    });
```

If not, can you tell me what library you're using for this autocomplete-function?

Comment: Well according to the tags I would have assumed http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ - but since that does not even have settings like `serviceUrl`, your guess is probably the right one.

Comment: Works with minChars! Thank you. However I'm using jquery.autocomplete.js library